# error while installing github package and internal server error when runnig help() function

Tags: r, github, installation, package, remotes

I am trying to install the brainconn package. I do not know whether something went wrong during installation, but I used the following options:

```
remotes::install_github("sidchop/brainconn", force = TRUE,
build_vignettes = TRUE, build = FALSE)
```

When I run

```
library(brainconn)
x <- example_unweighted_undirected
brainconn(atlas ="schaefer300_n7", conmat= as.data.frame(x), node.size = 3, view="ortho")
```

this returns the following error:

```
Error in `handlers[[1L]]()`:
! No layout function defined for objects of class <matrix>
```

and moreover, after installation, by running the `help()` of function with `?brainconn` I can see
image

[image]

I cannot understand what it is going wrong. Can anyone suggest some workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That was mentioned in [`sidchop/brainconn` issue 27](https://github.com/sidchop/brainconn/issues/27), and supposed to be fixed with [PR 28](https://github.com/sidchop/brainconn/pull/28):

> ### Fix matrix data error
>
> RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
> use `as.data.frame(conmat)` instead of `as.matrix(conmat)`

But, as you have seen, it is not enough.

Note that [issue 31](https://github.com/sidchop/brainconn/issues/31) reports a similar problem, on macOS 13.6.1 with R 4.3.1.

> I have just upgraded from Catalina to Ventura, with new R and RStudio installations. I believe all dependencies are present and freshly installed.

So the platform/OS might be important.

---

From the code alone ([`brainconn.R`](https://github.com/sidchop/brainconn/blob/4ff8af1b45395ae446783467a55e96a06e74d65b/R/brainconn.R#L111)):

- The function attempts to convert the `conmat` parameter to a matrix using `as.matrix(conmat)`. So, it should accept a data frame or a matrix, and it will convert it to a matrix internally if it is not already one.
- It checks if the matrix is symmetric using `isSymmetric.matrix(conmat)`. If the matrix is symmetric, it sets `directed <- FALSE`; otherwise, `directed <- TRUE`. That influences whether the function expects to plot undirected or directed edges.
- If `all.nodes` is `FALSE`, it will only include nodes with edges. That is done by checking each row and column in the `conmat` for non-zero values.
- It allows for thresholding the `conmat` using the `thr` and `uthr` parameters to exclude edges below or above certain values.

So make sure that:

- the `conmat` is of the correct dimensions, corresponding to the number of regions in the atlas.
- the matrix should be correctly formatted as either a symmetric matrix for undirected graphs or a non-symmetric matrix for directed graphs.
- the matrix values should be appropriate for the type of graph they are plotting (binary for unweighted, numerical values for weighted).
- all necessary dependencies, especially `ggraph`, `cowplot`, `grid`, and `OpenImageR`, are correctly installed and loaded.
- the atlas provided (either one of the included atlases or a custom atlas) is correctly formatted.

Comment: I tried to convert It as dataframe but It Dora not work. But are you basically suggesting that Windows 11 does note support that package?

Comment: @12666727b9 It is possible that Windows 11 might not support it: can you try in a WSL2 Linux session, to see if the error persists?

Comment: It Is strange. Because other package working like that such as ggbrain or something like that allow to visualize brain model and work fine on Windows 11.

Comment: @12666727b9 In addition to the WSL2 test, I have added some suggestions, after checking the code of `brainconn.R`.

Comment: Really thank you for the details you have checked. But I guess that my problem Has to do with installation 'cause I cannot do access either to help function, which something I could do before reinstalling it for mamy times

Comment: @12666727b9 Can you try a clean removal? (`remove.packages("brainconn")`). And restart the R session to clear any in-memory artifacts that might cause conflicts. Then `install.packages("processx")` and `install.packages("remotes")`, and `remotes::install_github("sidchop/brainconn")`. (check for any errors or warnings that appear during the installation process). Test if the help function works for brainconn: `library(brainconn)` and `?brainconn`.

Comment: Thanks. I can access to the help of brainconn package. But unfortunately it does not work. I am still getting the error

Comment: @12666727b9 Still the exact same error message?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same error

Answer (score 1):

try converting your connectivity matrix (as.data.frame(x)) into a numeric matrix using as.matrix().

library(brainconn)

x <- example_unweighted_undirected
conn_matrix <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(x))

brainconn(atlas = "schaefer300_n7", conmat = conn_matrix, node.size = 3, view = "ortho")

This ensures that the input to brainconn is a numeric matrix.

Comment: Hi. This is actually the solution that I have attempted, as I said in the comments. But unfortunately it does not work